# Home network port forwarding nightmare

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, port

Alright, this has been working *somehow* as it is till now, but lately I started getting issues. The setup is:

- a cable (internet)
- Linksys E4200 router
- a bunch of hardware (TV, unmanaged switches, printer, some PCs, PS4, network storage/server)
- some wireless stuff too (smartphones, laptops).

I have router set up with DHCP assigning static IPs by MAC, NAT type 2 (by ps4 terms), and UPnP enabled.

It all worked well up until I added network storage/server. To be able to access it's FTP/media features from outside of network I manually forwarded a number of required port on router and it worked fine.

Now I have some issues with other devices on network, namely PCs and PS4, which after some research I suspect to be caused by that port forwarding - some of them require exactly same ports forwarded to them as the network storage.

For example most of them require port 80 and 21 being available, and that's where is my question.

With given info:

1. Does manual port forwarding conflict/prevent UPnP port forwarding?
2. Is there better way (security-wise and reliability-wise) to set up my hardware?

If some additional info is needed I will provide it.

Answer (score 0):

> Does manual port forwarding conflict/prevent UPnP port forwarding?

They'll override whatever UPnP tries to do.

> Is there better way (security-wise and reliability-wise) to set up my hardware?

Do not open 80 if possible. Its the first port external actors will scan when trawling the net. You really dont wan't to expose your NAS unless you REALLY trust it. Think about all the security patches your PC gets, chances are your NAS will get 1-2 FW updates and most vulnerabilities found in future will never be fixed on it.

21 is FTP, which is notorious for its insecurity. Its even more advisable that you don't expose this.

Anecdotally I encountered many consumer embedded NAS units when working the helpdesk in an ISP that would riddle the whole NAT table with items and cause all kinds of problems (like DNS not working!). By far not all of them are like this, but it was common enough to be something we'd look for as soon as we saw strange behaviour with certain services. The idea setup to avoid this kind of stuff is some kind of VPN where you tunnel back to your own network and then access the NAS's services via that tunnel. Most will support SSH which can reasonably easily be used as a tunnel, PuttyTray is great for this on windows.

Comment: Thanks for a really interesting answer. I actually am aware about VPN, but somehow the idea of setting up one didn't occur to me up until your post. Still it leaves the part of question about UPnP and situations when several clients in my lan all require same port on router. Most games actually require some ports to be open (and that's the biggest issue, as some ports they require overlap, and some of my family members like to play at the same time.

Comment: If you have two Xboxs(especially 360s) its not your fault, some titles for them have hard coded ports and dont allow for two consoles at the same time. Clients should connect on port X and then setup a session on port Y dynamically using UPnP so that they dont collide with each other. The consoles shouldnt need 80 or 21, they're reserved service ports.